# Обработка массива обьектов

Tags: javascript

Как можно обработать массив обьектов, чтобы суммировать все поля сost (из Detail) со статусами true при совпадении свойства country? Спасибо!

```
let arr = [
  {
    "Company": "ААА",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Detail": [{
      "number": "256",
      "cost": 170,
      "status": false,
    }, {
      "number": "345",
      "cost": 720,
      "status": true,
    }, {
      "number": "569",
      "cost": 702,
      "status": false,
    }],
    "orderID": "564"
  },
  {
    "Company": "BBB",
    "Country": "CANADA",
    "Detail": [{
      "number": "589",
      "cost": 40,
      "status": true,
    }, {
      "number": "354",
      "cost": 90,
      "status": true,
    }, {
      "number": "478",
      "cost": 780,
      "status": true,
    }],
    "orderID": "594"
  },
  {
    "Company": "AAA",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Detail": [{
      "number": "154",
      "cost": 140,
      "status": true,
    }, {
      "number": "148",
      "cost": 920,
      "status": false,
    }, {
      "number": "954",
      "cost": 680,
      "status": true,
    }],
    "orderID": "514"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{
    "Company": "ААА",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Detail": [{
      "number": "256",
      "cost": 170,
      "status": false,
    }, {
      "number": "345",
      "cost": 720,
      "status": true,
    }, {
      "number": "569",
      "cost": 702,
      "status": false,
    }],
    "orderID": "564"
  },{
    "Company": "BBB",
    "Country": "CANADA",
    "Detail": [{
      "number": "589",
      "cost": 40,
      "status": true,
    }, {
      "number": "354",
      "cost": 90,
      "status": true,
    }, {
      "number": "478",
      "cost": 780,
      "status": true,
    }],
    "orderID": "594"
  },{
    "Company": "AAA",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Detail": [{
      "number": "154",
      "cost": 140,
      "status": true,
    }, {
      "number": "148",
      "cost": 920,
      "status": false,
    }, {
      "number": "954",
      "cost": 680,
      "status": true,
    }],
    "orderID": "514"
  }
];


console.log(
  arr
    .filter(el => el.Country === 'USA')
    .reduce((sum, el) => 
      sum + el.Detail.reduce((dsum, detail) => 
        dsum + (+detail.status) * detail.cost
      ,0) 
    ,0)
);
```